# I want to resolve Redirect Chain

Tags: redirect, htaccess

Anyone who can guide me in this matter, I want to resolve the redirect chain?

- `http://www.example.com`
- redirect to `https://www.example.com`
- and then redirect to `https://example.com`.

I want to redirect directly from `http://www.example.com` to `https://example.com`.

Redirection plugins in WordPress are not working, as they are only worked with to redirect pages or posts.

This is a redirection code in .htaccess.

```
# BEGIN rlrssslReallySimpleSSL rsssl_version[3.3.5]
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on RewriteCond %{HTTP:CF-Visitor} '"scheme":"http"'
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !wp-content\/cache\/(all|wpfc-mobile-cache)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
# END rlrssslReallySimpleSSL
```

Comment: Can you show us how your redirects are configured? Are both redirects generated by WordPress, or is one in your web server configuration? I see you've tagged this .htaccess.

Comment: "they are only worked with to redirect pages or posts" - What do you mean by this? _Aside:_ The redirect "chain" you describe isn't necessarily a bad thing and in some cases is actually recommended/required.

Comment: How are those redirects implemented?

Comment: @Rup actually, I don't know the location of this problem. I have set https://example.com in the site Address setting(WordPress). This is a redirection code in .htaccess.# BEGIN rlrssslReallySimpleSSL rsssl_version[3.3.5]
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:CF-Visitor} '"scheme":"http"'
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !wp-content\/cache\/(all|wpfc-mobile-cache)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
# END rlrssslReallySimpleSSL

Comment: @Subhan Please edit your question to add the contents of your `.htaccess` file in order to retain formatting. (Comments are not for code dumps.)

Comment: @MrWhite, i mean, redirection plugins in WordPress only worked, if we want to redirect the old/broken link to a new page/post. This is not working, when I set HTTP://www.example.com to https://example.com.

Comment: @MrWhite, Done! Thanks for the suggestions...

Comment: @TomJNowell, That's what I don't know!

Comment: Try `curl -D - http://www.example.com/` from a command prompt: this will show you the actual redirect you're getting. Ditto the second redirect. I'd guess the WordPress generated ones will have Link: or X-Pingback headers.

Comment: @Rup, yes it redirects to [https://www.example.com] but i want to redirect to without www version.

Comment: OK but there might be information in those redirects that will help you figure out what is generating them.

Comment: You need to discover how those redirects are implemented, without knowing this question is impossible to answer, you may need to speak with your hosting provider. It's clear the http -> https redirect is done via HTAccess and it looks like reallysimpleSSL added that, but it is not clear where the www redirect comes from. Note that 3rd party plugin support is offtopic on this site

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
> ```

Replace `%{HTTP_HOST}` with your canonical hostname. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

You will need to clear your browser cache before testing.

Comment: Can you guide where to place this code?

Comment: This is just a small change to your existing code. I have quoted the line of code (from your question) that would need to be changed. (Although it looks like that code might be managed by a plugin - "rlrssslReallySimpleSSL rsssl_version[3.3.5]"?)